# What's the best way to declare Color for SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

What's the best way to declare Color for SwiftUI ?

I've `ColorSet.xcassets` and I need to provide some class or enum or extension that easiest to use with components.

```swift
import SwiftUI

extension Color {

    public static let baseGrayLight = Color("baseGrayLight")
    public static let baseGrayMedium = Color("baseGrayMedium")

}
```

I think extension may be the best way because it doesn't need to class name everywhere to use. But it doesn't work in SwiftUI because component's arguments aren't only `Color`.

- `fill()` required `FillStyle`
- `foregroundColor()` required Color ✅

I'm not sure others function that may require others class. How it should be ? What's class type I need to use ?

[image]

I need some standard to help me to resolve this issues.

Comment: I was developed swift in UIKit style before. I used to select extension for this. It's very easy to find color by type dot `.` in arguments.

Comment: See also the section about Asset Catalogs in the [Xcode 15 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-15-release-notes#Asset-Catalogs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to avoid writing the name of the enclosing type (e.g. `Color`) all the time, you can write it as an extension of `ShapeStyle where Self == Color`:

```
extension ShapeStyle where Self == Color {
    static var fooColor: Color {
        Color("foo")
    }
}
```

Note that when you write e.g. `fill(.red)`, you are calling [this overload](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/circle/fill(_:style:)), taking a `ShapeStyle`, and optionally a `FillStyle`. Do not confuse this with [the overload](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/circle/fill(style:)) that takes only a `FillStyle`.

You don't need to worry about "others function that may require others class", because there is no "others class" [sic]. `Color` only conforms a fixed set of protocols. Of those, only [`ShapeStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shapestyle) declares the built-in color constants.

You don't need to redeclare these again in a `Color` extension, because `Color` conforms to `ShapeStyle`.

By declaring your custom colors in `ShapeStyle`, you ensured that everywhere you can use a built-in color without the `Color.` prefix, you can use your own custom color without the `Color.` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to declare a color it to use a Color asset. Once you create a color asset you will get a visual of it and can also use it directly to your code.
It will also organize your all colors in one place